# Apart from the official bitcoin client what other clients are there?

Tags: client

Apart from the official client found at the [bitcoin.org](http://www.bitcoin.org/) site what is the list of alternative bitcoin clients? And what OS do they work on?

Comment: As far as I know the official client is currently the only client capable of doing full transaction validation. (BitcoinJ, libbitcoin, and Armory don't do full validation. Some other clients rely on bitcoind or the partially-validating clients.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a current list of clients here
http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Category:Clients

There is development discussion around alternative clients here
http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=37.0

Currently the "Official Client" (more specifically, the Satoshi client) is the most widely used and has implementations that run on Windows, OS X, and Linux. However, multiple alternative clients have been developed, including ones that run on Android, and this is currently a high priority for the bitcoin community.

The current most popular alternative clients are BitcoinJ, written in java
http://code.google.com/p/bitcoinj/

and BitDroid, which runs on Android
https://github.com/cdecker/BitDroid-Network

Comment: I upvoted this but I feel it's worth noting that BitcoinJ and BitDroid aren't really "clients" per se - more like engines. I know technically they satisfy the criteria in the same way that bitcoind.exe does, but when most folks say "clients" they're probably expecting a fully functioning app with a GUI.

Comment: yes, that is very true. Perhaps worth noting that they are still more suitable for developers to build GUIs and other features around than useful on their own for the average user at this point.

Comment: I found this site which has an alternative client http://multibit.org/

Comment: The list of current clients is quite useless. It does not say which clients are desktop versions, etc and some links are dead

Comment: yes someone should submit a new answer, or re-ask the question and answer it. Unfortunately, lots of questions like these are going to be time-limited in the bitcoin world.

Answer (score 2):

[LoveBitcoins.org](http://lovebitcoins.org) has a [list of clients](http://lovebitcoins.org/getStarted.html) for various platforms.

Comment: It's missing a lot of more common clients.